# How can we use multi color icon in android notification icon

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, notification-icons

I have already tried with transparent background, it's working fine but I need more than 1 color in the notification small icon.

When I am trying to get results find whatever color we use that will change by icon color what we give in our code only transparent color is always transparent.

I have tried custom layout notifications but I got stuck with android 11 some devices work fine but some devices show a grey square icon.

I want a notification icon with multi-color in the status bar and when we expand notifications.

Answer (score 0):

As of android V5.0.0 i.e target sdk version 21, android will always tint your notification icon on the status bar. On Scrolling down the notifications on your lock screen in the newer version you can show a custom icon that can be of any color but on the status bar you wont be able to show multi color icons.

Comment: some apps have multicolor notification icon in status bar and scrolling down both place, i already done with status bar icon colored but when i scroll down then it shows grey icon

Comment: i am not sure how but a game has monochrome color on my phone but have multi colored image on my friends phone. i think it might be related to android version but i am not sure